# datepicker format not working

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I tried to fix this but its just not working. It outputs like: 08/15/2016 but I want it like that: 15.08.2016. I tried also with "dateFormat" but it didn't work either.

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
nowTemp.setDate(nowTemp.getDate()+1);

var fromEndDate = new Date();

$(function() {

    $('#dpd1').datepicker({
        startDate: nowTemp,
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
    });

    $('#dpd2').datepicker({
        endDate: fromEndDate,
        autoclose: true,
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
    });

});


var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
    }
    checkin.hide();
    $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');

var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }

}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

The below code is to disable past dates and the option to select in dpd2 only future dates.

Answer (score 0):

Change "  " to '  '

```
$(function() {

    $('#dpd1').datepicker({
        startDate: nowTemp,
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    });

    $('#dpd2').datepicker({
        endDate: fromEndDate,
        autoclose: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
    });

});
```

Do the test without the rest of the script, to be sure that the problem is in this function.

The code works fine, maybe the error is in another place.
https://jsfiddle.net/iandrabedin/09sh7b86/

Comment: Try with a comma after the first dateFormat (and maybe after the first selector). I edited my code to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

```js
$('#txtDob').datepicker({
  format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
  autoclose: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <label for="txtDob"></label>
  <input type="text" id="txtDob" />
</form>
```